# Can't login to Ubuntu anymore

Tags: login

Ubuntu no longer lets me login.  I type my password into the login screen and hit enter and the screen goes black then brings me directly back to the login screen.  It gives me no messages either.  I know for a fact I am typing the correct password.  Anybody know whats going on?  My home folder is also encrypted and I am running 11.10

Thanks

Comment: If you press Control+Alt+F1 you should see a text-mode login screen. Can you test that to make sure it's accepting your username and password.

Comment: Logging in through the console appears to work perfectly fine.  I'm totally lost as to what is going on.

Comment: Sounds to me like X (the graphical server) is crashing at some point and it's just reloading (that's why you're being pushed back to the login screen). If you have a network connection please run `sudo apt-get install pastebinit`, then `pastebinit /var/log/Xorg.0.log` and then post the URL it generates back here so we can see what X did last time it loaded.

Comment: Ok i seem to have solved the problem.  I was unable to access my home directory when I was using the console so i changed the permissions of it to 777.  When i restarted my computer i was able to login.  Very weird.

Comment: Very odd indeed. Glad you fixed it.

Comment: I am having the same trouble because i removed pm-utils package from my system.
I'll post here the answer as soon as I find out how to get rid of it.

Comment: 777 ? **Dangerous!!**

Answer (score 1):

*(Comment from OP fixed issue)*

Sounds to me like X (the graphical server) is crashing at some point and it's just reloading (that's why you're being pushed back to the login screen). If you have a network connection please run `sudo apt-get install pastebinit`, then `pastebinit /var/log/Xorg.0.log` and then post the URL it generates back here so we can see what X did last time it loaded. – Oli♦ Oct 20 '11 at 1:0

Ok i seem to have solved the problem. I was unable to access my home directory when I was using the console so i changed the permissions of it to 777. When i restarted my computer i was able to login. Very weird. – matthew Oct 20 '11 at 1:12

Comment: "Fixing" anything by setting the permissions of your *home directory* to 777 is like leaving the front door open when you leave your house - because you once lost your key.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had the same graphical login problem (on Ubuntu Precise 12.04). The cause was also permission-related but slightly different from the OP’s cause: the `.Xauthority` file in my home directory was owned by `root`. Removing that file from a text-mode login screen (e.g., Ctrl+Alt+F1, log in, then `sudo rm .Xauthority`) solved the graphical login problem for me.

Answer (score -2):

Same prob with .Xauthority owned by root.

Fixed by removing it.

Possibly caused by starting vncserver as root.