# I can't access my session

Tags: 13.04, session

I have a problem with the authentication page, it keeps sending me back, even if I have the correct password, I've looked for the problem, but no solution worked for me.
the .Xauthority is the problem I guess, because it's empty, the file is already the property of the user.

P.S: if I enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and login, everything is good, but if I try to execute startx it shows my wallpaper with no panels nor icons.

Comment: If it's because of your _Display Manager_ this could help: [Fix Log-in Screen loop problem: reinstall _DM_!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/387112/login-goes-back-to-login-screen/387136#387136)

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it didn't work, but thx anyway :)

Comment: Here's another link, hope this time you get your system fixed: [Remove and Re-Install Unity and ubuntu-desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/131016/how-can-i-remove-and-re-install-unity). (Or you could install other desktop environments like gnome3, cinnamon, and log in with these envs. selected instead of Unity/Unity2d)... regards...

Answer (score 0):

Had some kind of the same problem, but I screwed up video drivers. It was exactly the same - nothing shows up, not even action bar at top. In my case I had to reinstall, and I may be afraid that you'll have to do the same. Backup your most careful data somewhere using some live session, so you don't lose anything. I'm sorry for you, I know how it feels.

Comment: the problem is i reinstalled ubuntu 2 times now and the same problem occurs i really don't know what to do ! 
is there anyway to regenerate .Xauthority file ?

Comment: Format the disk entirely. Twice to be safe. Try to install Ubuntu 13.10, it works pretty much the same, but it's a newer one :)