# Login on 14.04 keeps taking me back to login

Tags: 14.04, login

I can't login to Ubuntu anymore. When I enter my password correctly, the screen goes blank for a split-second, then comes right back to the login screen. Even if I sign in as a guest, the same thing happens.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on ASUS ROG G751 series G751JT-DH72 gaming laptop, with Nvidia GTX 970M video card. FWIW, I had to manually install the video card driver from the Internet about a week ago. (But was able to log in many times this week with no problem until now.)

I found these questions: [Login goes back to login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387112/login-goes-back-to-login-screen), [Can't login to Ubuntu 14.04 after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454576/cant-login-to-ubuntu-14-04-after-upgrade), [Can't login to Ubuntu anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69546/cant-login-to-ubuntu-anymore)

And the only commands I tried are:

sudo chown 777 .Xauthority

sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /home/[username]  (yes, I know giving execute permissions to everything in my home directory was unnecessary, but oh well... xD)

And neither worked. Exact same thing keeps happening. I'm now hesitant to try anything else until you guys can see my pastebin (http://paste.ubuntu.com/11842315/) and hopefully help me figure out what the problem may be in my specific case. Thanks!

Comment: try using this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) which has helped many

Comment: Any chance your partition is full? Try df -h

Answer (score 0):

Have you deleted the `.Xauthority` file? It should fix the problem:

```
sudo rm ~/.Xauthority
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your suspicion of the video drivers is correct. I had exactly this problem when trying (and *eventually* getting to work!) the `fglrx` driver for my AMD/ATI card and Ubuntu 15.04.

From your pastebin, it looks like you've had an update to the kernel and the video driver is now broke. I think it's after login that Ubuntu tries to switch the video mode to hardware accelerated.

```
    NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
    [    30.159] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
    [    30.159] (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
    [    30.159] (EE) [drm] KMS not enabled
```

My advice is to search the internet for how to remove the Nvidia driver completely which should return you to a workable system. Then follow instructions to reinstall. As I said, I had to do that a few times before I got my video driver working.

One way you can do this is with `<Ctrl>+<Alt>+<F1>` and something like

```
    sudo apt-get remove --purge <Nvidia package>
```

(example: [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely))

Or, I found that I could get a working desktop with LXDE even with broken video drivers. If you have other desktop environments you can choose it from the login screen by clicking on the Ubuntu logo next to your login name.

Reboot after removing the broken driver before starting to install again. Hope this helps get you back to a usable system!

Comment: Yes, reinstalling the graphics card driver worked. Thanks a bunch! What with an Ubuntu update coming every few days, I hope I don't have to do this too frequently...

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :) Lookup DKMS for your Nvidia drivers, that should fix up the driver when a new kernel comes along